# At SFSafariViewController dismiss, disable status bar hide animation [iOS 9]

Tags: ios9

I need to disable the "hide animation" of the status bar when the SFSafariViewController is dismissed.
After a normal Facebook login, permission request.

Because makes a bad animation on frame change..

In my storyboard the status bar is hidden and my views have a constraint "Top space to: Top layout"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the solution:

If i create and present `SFSafariViewController` with:

```
#import <SafariServices/SafariServices.h>


SFSafariViewController *sfc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
sfc.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:sfc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Implementing the delegate ( `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate` ) method:

```
- (void)safariViewControllerDidFinish:(SFSafariViewController *)controller
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

The VC is presented beautifully without status bar! And doesn't make a bad effect during dismiss.

---

Implementing just the delegate method works perfectly even with a `SFSafariViewController` called by Facebook SDK (4.6.0 from CocoaPods)

**EDIT:**

Doing other tests, looks like the delegate method doesn't work as expected;

**But** just implementing:

```
View controller-based status bar appearance : FALSE
```

In the .plist file is enough to hide the status bar in a `SFSafariViewController`

Comment: I tried adding the `View controller-based status bar appearance` with a setting of `NO` to the Info.plist file but it did not work.

Comment: Also using `setStatusBarHidden` is deprecated in iOS 9.