# FB SDK - safari doesn't dismiss

Tags: ios, facebook

When user tries to auth in app using facebook, safari window doesnt disappear after user grants permissions inside it. Safari reloads page and remains blank, not dismissing and not returning user to app

My appDelegate methods are following

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

     FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

 return true

 }

 func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

 }
```

Where can be the problem ?

Comment: It could be the equivalent of this general problem for Safari: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583765/at-sfsafariviewcontroller-dismiss-disable-status-bar-hide-animation-ios-9/32584054#32584054  You may need to implement SafarServices, set a delegate and add the method `safariViewControllerDidFinish`.

Comment: There;s no such thing as `SafarServices` -- should be `SafariServices`.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample Xcode project on github that replicates this behaviour?